# How to call a function a in plpgsql which has a return data type of void?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

```
create or replace function f1() //procedure should display 9
returns void
as $$
declare age int default 9; //variable declaration
begin                     
select age;      //prints 9
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

I keep receiving this error

```
perform f1();
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "perform"
LINE 1: perform f1();
```

Comment: `PERFORM` is not an SQL statement. Don't mix up SQL and PL/pgSQL, they are different languages. Apart from that, `SELECT` does not print anything.

Comment: i really appreciate you help its been a little difficulr jumping from mysql to psql in terms of procedures

Answer (score 1):

`perform` is a PL/pgSQL statement. In plain SQL, you simply use SELECT:

```
select f1();
```

---

Note that the function as written, will **not** "print 9" - it will result in an error as the result of a `SELECT` needs to be stored somewhere. In PL/pgSQL you would need the `RAISE` statement to "print" something:

```
create or replace function f1()
returns void
as $$
declare
  age int default 9; 
begin                     
  raise 'Age: ', age; -- this prints 9
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

---

If you want a function to "display" something, it might make more sense to let the function *return* a result:

```
create or replace function f1()
returns int
as $$
declare
  age int default 9; 
begin                     
  return age;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Then `select f1()` will "print" `9`